# Manage module trees with ActiveSupport

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activesupport

I have a Rails project **MyApp** which I fragmented into multiple gems. One of them is to manage users.

Considering that I want code reloading and auto-require from ActiveSupport, along namespaced folders to require files. I can organize my code this way:

```
# MyApp::Users
./lib/my_app/users
./app/controllers/my_app/users/
./rspec/unit/my_app/users/
```

The above way is the most clean one, but results on long nested routes with the repeated pattern `my_app/users/`, which can be exhausting for lazy programmers. Since I still need the folder namespace to differentiate code from different gems,  I thought about abusing the root namespace:

```
# Users
./lib/users
./app/controllers/users/
./rspec/unit/users/
```

That is not as clean and the more I fragment into gems, the higher my chances to have a namespace collision.

Which organization pattern is the most commonly used? Which is the Rails way?

For a library the first one seems the best one, but for a large application it feels tiring having all the time long paths and maybe the fear for name collision is doing more harm than good.

Comment: a gem has its own name so its own namespace, I'm not sure I understand the problem